# Delete session.storage on changing restaurant page

Tags: session, vuejs2, routes, cart

I'm using Vuejs 2 and vue router to create this website.
It has a cart saved in session.storage.
I would like to delete the cart (session.storage) when the restaurant page change.
I've tried to save the slug of the restaurant and compare it to the current slug:

```
 setSlug() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("slug", this.$route.params.slug);
    },

    checkSlug() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("slug") != this.$route.params.slug) {
            sessionStorage.clear();
        }
    },
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

**TheRestaurant.vue**

```
export default {
name: "TheRestaurant",
data() {
    return {
        restaurant: {},
        cart: {},
        quantity: 1,
        partialTotal: 0,
        total: 0,
    };
},
methods: {
    //get the restaurant and the dishes with axios call and set the data
    getRestaurant() {
        axios
            .get("/api/restaurants/" + this.$route.params.slug)
            .then((response) => {
                this.restaurant = response.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
    showDetails(id) {
        let modal = document.getElementById("modal-" + id);
        modal.classList.replace("d-none", "d-flex");
    },
    hideDetails(id) {
        let modal = document.getElementById("modal-" + id);
        modal.classList.replace("d-flex", "d-none");
    },
    addToCart(dish) {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("cart") == null) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify([]));
        }
        let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
        let index = cart.findIndex((item) => item.id == dish.id);
        if (index == -1) {
            dish.quantity = 1;
            cart.push(dish);
        } else {
            cart[index].quantity++;
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
        this.cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
        this.partialTotal = round(
            this.cart.reduce(
                (acc, dish) => acc + dish.price * dish.quantity,
                0
            ),
            2
        );
        sessionStorage.setItem(
            "partialTotal",
            JSON.stringify(this.partialTotal)
        );
        this.total = this.partialTotal + this.restaurant.delivery_price;
        sessionStorage.setItem("total", JSON.stringify(this.total));
    },
    removeOneFromCart(dish) {
        let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
        let index = cart.findIndex((item) => item.id == dish.id);
        if (index !== -1) {
            cart[index].quantity--;
            if (cart[index].quantity == 0) {
                cart.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
        this.cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
        this.partialTotal = round(
            this.cart.reduce(
                (acc, dish) => acc + dish.price * dish.quantity,
                0
            ),
            2
        );
        sessionStorage.setItem(
            "partialTotal",
            JSON.stringify(this.partialTotal)
        );

        this.total = this.partialTotal + this.restaurant.delivery_price;
        sessionStorage.setItem("total", JSON.stringify(this.total));
    },
    removeAllFromCart(dish) {
        let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
        let index = cart.findIndex((item) => item.id == dish.id);
        if (index !== -1) {
            cart.splice(index, 1);
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
        this.cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
        this.partialTotal = round(
            this.cart.reduce(
                (acc, dish) => acc + dish.price * dish.quantity,
                0
            ),
            2
        );
        sessionStorage.setItem(
            "partialTotal",
            JSON.stringify(this.partialTotal)
        );

        this.total = this.partialTotal + this.restaurant.delivery_price;
        sessionStorage.setItem("total", JSON.stringify(this.total));
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.getRestaurant();
    this.cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
    this.partialTotal = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("partialTotal"));
    this.total = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("total"));
},
};
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Restaurant from "./pages/TheRestaurant.vue";
import Home from "./pages/TheMain.vue";
import Cart from "./pages/TheCart.vue";
import Search from "./pages/AdvancedSearch.vue";

//put all the different pages below

Vue.use(VueRouter);

/**
 * @type {import("vue-router").RouteConfig[]}
 */

const routes = [
    {
    path: "/",
    component: Home,
    name: "home.index",
    meta: {
        title: "Deliveboo Homepage",
    },
},
{
    path: "/cart",
    component: Cart,
    name: "cart.index",
    meta: {
        title: "Deliveboo Cart",
    },
},
{
    path: "/search",
    component: Search,
    name: "search.index",
    meta: {
        title: "Deliveboo Search Restaurants",
    },
},
{
    path: "/:slug",
    component: Restaurant,
    name: "restaurant.index",
    meta: {
        title: "Deliveboo Restaurant",
    },
},
];

const router = new VueRouter({
//it must contain an array of routes

routes,
mode: "history",
});



export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your hierarchy and logic of components correctly,
in the **mounted** hook of Home and Search components you can reset your session.storage.